# How to convert SWF file to XML using java?

Tags: java, xml, flash

Is there any possibilities to decompile and convert a SWF file into an XML file using Java?

I tried to use [shark -Flash2XML](http://developer.berlios.de/projects/spark-xml/) but it doesn't provide any output. I tried to analyse code, but cant get any result out of it.

Can anyone share some working code that uses SWF2XML or Flash2XML